# English edition of Vol 9 of Dieudonné's Foundations of Modern Analysis?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I have found the first 8 volumes of Dieudonné's *Foundations of Modern Analysis* in English translation, but I'm having difficulty locating volume 9. I have searched the catalogues of numerous libraries including the British Library and Library of Congress. Does an English language edition of the 9th volume actually exist?

The 9th volume of the original French language series (*Éléments d'Analyse*) comprises chapter 24 and is entitled *Topologie algébrique et topologie différentielle élémentaire* (*Algebraic Topology and Basic Differential Topology*).

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Harry

Answer (score 1):

According to this [biography of Dieudonné](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1G2-2830905623.html), only the first eight volumes were translated into English. :(

Comment: Actually, the first volume was originally written in english, so there are 7 volumes translated into english.